I can't convert View to PDF in some versions
I have an app in SwiftUI and in it I have a ScrollView with some patient data to convert into PDF, it's a rather extensive scrollview, on my physical device iPhone 7 with iOS 15 it works perfectly, however on a friend's iPhone 11 with iOS 17 the device freezes the moment he clicks on the button that generates the PDF, I also tested it on a simulated iPhone 15 Pro with iOS 17 and it gave the same problem as on my friend's physical device, on the 3rd generation iPhone SE it crashes but shows an error in Xcode, something that it didn't show in other simulators
This is the button that calls the code
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                HStack {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        if included && !saving {
                                            if signatureImage != nil {
                                                exportPDF(name: "ToR-\(patient.name)-\(patient.id)") {
                                                    self
                                                } completion: { status, url in
                                                    if let url = url, status {
                                                        self.PDFUrl = url
                                                        self.showActionSheet.toggle()
                                                        print("URL => \(url) - Status \(status)")
                                                    } else {
                                                        print("Failed")
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                self.scrollToBottom = true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }) {
                                        if saving {
                                            ProgressView()
                                                .tint(Color("MainColor"))
                                                .scaleEffect(1.5)
                                        } else {
                                            Text(NSLocalizedString("Save", comment: ""))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            )

And this is the code
//
//  PdfGenerator.swift
//  Podana-SwiftUI
//
//  Created by Henrique Pedro on 27/06/24.
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

extension View {
    func convertToScrollView<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content()).view!
        hostingController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let constraints = [
            hostingController.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            hostingController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            hostingController.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            hostingController.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenBounds().width)
        ]
        scrollView.addSubview(hostingController)
        scrollView.addConstraints(constraints)
        scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()

        return scrollView
    }

    func exportPDF<Content: View>(name: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content, completion: @escaping (Bool, URL?) -> ()) {
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let outputFileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).pdf")

        let pdfView = convertToScrollView {
            content()
        }
        pdfView.tag = 1009
        let size = pdfView.contentSize
        pdfView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: getSafeArea().top, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        
        getRootController().view.insertSubview(pdfView, at: 0)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

            do {
                try renderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { context in
                    context.beginPage()
                    pdfView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
                })
                
                completion(true, outputFileURL)
            }
            catch {
                completion(false, nil)
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            pdfView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func screenBounds() -> CGRect {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds
    }

    func getRootController() -> UIViewController {
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
            return .init()
        }

        guard let root = screen.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
            return .init()
        }

        return root
    }

    func getSafeArea() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
            return .zero
        }

        guard let safeArea = screen.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets else {
            return .zero
        }

        return safeArea
    }
}


This is the line pointed out in the error
pdfView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
And this is the error that appears
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
